# How to integrate Pentaho with .NET

Tags: pentaho

I have been looking for some tutorials or articles, how I could integrate [Pentaho](http://reporting.pentaho.com/) with .NET, but looks like there is nothing at all. No examples, no articles.

Is it possible at all? Any links would be useful.

Thank you.

Comment: what sort of integration do you want between pentaho and .NET?

Answer (score 0):

what sort of integration do you want between pentaho and .NET?

We can do integration with .net:

Follow the below steps:

If you created jobs and transformations in pentaho then you want schedule the jobs using .net then create the .BAT file using pentaho and call the .BAT file from .NET

Regards
Prasada